# AudioUnitSetProperty Swift errors

Tags: ios, swift, audio, core-data, audiounit

I am trying to set the bands in my equalizer by using AudioUnitSetProperty but cant figure out the syntax in Swift. My code looks like this:

```
var eqFrequencies: NSArray = [ 32, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 16000 ]
    var noBands = UInt32(eqFrequencies.count)

AudioUnitSetProperty(self.MyAppUnit, AudioUnitParameterID(kAUNBandEQProperty_NumberOfBands), AudioUnitScope(kAudioUnitScope_Global), 0, 6, UInt32(sizeof(noBands)))
```

Anyone know the correct way of doing this?

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: where you use 6 in your call there should be a pointer to the NSArray, shouldn't it :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (compiles for me in Xcode 6.3):

```
    var eqFrequencies: [UInt32] = [ 32, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 16000 ]

    AudioUnitSetProperty(
        self.MyAppUnit,
        AudioUnitPropertyID(kAUNBandEQProperty_NumberOfBands),
        AudioUnitScope(kAudioUnitScope_Global),
        0,
        eqFrequencies,
        UInt32(eqFrequencies.count*sizeof(UInt32))
    )
```

Swift griped about the various int types, hence the extra casts, and the size calculation was wrong, but the band swift array of `UInt32`s (*not* `NSArray`) should convert automatically to `UnsafePointer<Void>`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to compile for me. complains that: "Cannot invoke 'AudioUnitSetProperty' with an argument list of type '(AudioUnit, Uint32, Uint32, Int, NSArray, Uint32)".

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to mention that I changed the type

Comment: This does compile but when i adjust the equalizer only the first slider adjusts the sound and it seems to adjust ALL levels. Do you have any Idea why this may be?

Comment: I need to see more code to know why that's happening. Is that part of this question or a new question?

Comment: Your right that should be a new question, I will start a new one with more code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you have time here is the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29970220/core-audio-swift-equalizer-adjusts-all-bands-at-once